# SFTP WIndows Client

Tags: windows, sftp

Does anyone know of a good (free/open source) SFTP client for Windows.

Need to be able to:

1. sync a remote SFTP server with my local Windows folder to backup the remote to local.
2. to run this on a schedule and ideally as a Windows service.
3. Needs to be able to cope with lots of files and folders.
4. Only backup the changed.new files after the initial run.

This would be ideal however it does not run on a schedule without giving and error as it will not save the SSH key: http://fullsync.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Shopping and/or product recommendation questions are off-topic here. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) and [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

- I use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net), I really like that it allows you to import sessions from PuTTY.
- [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) - Yet another great project, maybe this will work better for you.
- [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)

Comment: WinSCP does not seem to work very well as we have tested it. Also have to script where a GUI would be easier.

Comment: @Adam, are you sure you've tried it? as WinSCP _IS_ GUI))

Comment: WinSCP is great, I like the portable version.
You can also try Cyberduck http://cyberduck.ch/
*OR* FileZilla http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php